# SDWebImage not caching

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I'm downloading images using [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL] with options set to 0.  I'm initially not doing anything with them, with the understanding that they will be cached.  However, when I use the exact same function to later display an image, the function is downloading the image again, rather than getting it from the cache (the image cache type is 0). In both cases, the url of the image is the same.  Is my understanding regarding caching incorrect?

Comment: Do you want to download some images and then save it inside your app or are you just trying to fill an imageView with some image from the internet?

Comment: I'm downloading them in the first place just to get them cached, so that when the user actually does want to see an image he doesn't have to wait.

Comment: @mbachrach If you're just prefetching the next few, that's fine. But if you're prefetching hundreds of images, that can be seriously problematic. Lazy loading is generally preferred over eager loading, and if you do eager loading, (a) don't use too much network resources; (b) prioritize current UI over background requests; (c) perhaps constrain the eager loading (e.g. on scroll, prefetch the next two images, but not all of them). Lots of issues there. Anyway, with my apologies, I'd updated my answer with some unsolicited thoughts about implications of eager loading process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to enjoy cache functionality is to use [`SDWebImageManager`](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Classes/SDWebImageManager.html) instead of [`SDWebImageDownload`](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Classes/SDWebImageDownloader.html). `SDWebImageManager` provides the `SDImageCache` functionality, whereas if you use `SDWebImageDownload`, you'll have to rely upon `NSURLCache` (which has limitations/issues) or write your own cache code.

Also (and implicit in Gustavo's question), if you're just trying to set the image of a `UIImageView`, it's actually even better to not use either of those classes, and use the `UIImageView+WebCache` category instead. It enjoys all of the cache abilities of `SDWebImageManager`, but also offers other advantages (esp for re-used `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` objects).

---

In a comment to another user, you say that you're downloading all of the images in advanced, "just to get them cached, so that when the user actually does want to see an image he doesn't have to wait."

That is a great stretch objective, but this sort of prefetch (sometimes call eager loading, in contrast to the more common lazy loading) has a couple of implications:

- Unless you're confident that the user really will need *all* of the images, this is an aggressive use of their mobile device's cellular data plan, so maybe you should only do this if on WiFi (which can be determined by [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)). Apple has even rejected apps for using too much cellular bandwidth.
- The app will be more aggressive than necessary in terms of memory (causing more suspended apps to be terminated, which doesn't affect the UX for your app, but Apple asks us all to be good citizens and not use more RAM than we need). Again, if the user was going to need *all* of the images, then it's a fine thing to do, but if not, one should really minimize memory consumption, not loading the cache up with stuff that might not be needed for the current session. Also note that downloading a bunch of stuff that might need to be downloaded, but was done simply as a precaution has (modest) battery implications, too.
- If you do a lot of requests for background data, make sure you're not using up all of the limited the network connections (you only have five) and backlogging the system with a lot of requests. The nice thing is that the UI `UIImageView` category naturally favors the current UI (being, fundamentally, a lazy-loading mechanism). But let's say there are 100 images, and the user fires the app and scrolls down to the bottom of the list. Do you really want the request for #90 (which is on screen and the user is waiting for) to wait for #1-89 to finish?

  See WWDC 2012 video [Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712), section 7, "Separate control and data flow", about 48 min into the video for a discussion of how this is problematic.

  If nothing else, I'd make sure that you test the app using the network link conditioner (part of the hardware IO tool for MacOS or under the Settings > General > Developer on the device). So turn on the network link conditioner, remove and reinstall the app (to empty the persistent storage cache), and then fire up the app with this slow connection, try navigating around while the image loading is in progress. A simple "let's kick off a prefetch of everything" may not offer the necessary prioritization of the current UI on a slow network that you really want.

All of this said, you may have thought through all of these implications, and if so, I apologize for belaboring the obvious. It's just that one has to be careful before implementing an aggressive pre-fetch of all images.

Comment: I was actually using the WebImageManager in one place, and the SDWebImageDownload in another:  everything gets a bit blurry at the end of the day.  Using the manager in both places now, and everything works as expected.  Thanks.